# identifying stack trace error based on condition

Tags: javascript

I am trying to show a different message when the users are getting local storage error. For both android and ios users who access the site. So the below are the two different error messages we are getting when html5 storage is turned off.

```
SecurityError: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document.

SecurityError: The operation is insecure.
```

So how can i identify that the security error is only related to html5 (local storage) so that i can show user a message. So apart from this local storage error it should be normal. Is there any status code or something which i can get the difference

Comment: Why not just check if `localStorage` is available, instead of relying on an error message?

Comment: Because I have written a page for showing error so there if I can identify from stacktrace it will be good so that the error page is common to entire application just only to show a different message layout is same

Comment: @yainspan is there a way or any resources. I wasn't able to find it